# Jquery ajax, trouble receiving huge amount of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nginx

I need to receive big amount of data via ajax response and seems like some kind of data size limit on live server(nginx) is causing trouble. On local test server( wamp ) and live shared hosting apache I have no limits or issues. The data is currently 2.7mb and it could get bigger. Problem is that the script is going to be used by multiple users and I cant force anyone to increase the post_max_size.

The script is fairly simple

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data: {
        'action': 'get_data',
    },
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {

        if (response.data.html !== null) {
            //process html 2.7MB
        }
    }

});
```

the reason why data is so big is json validation and html data must have special chars , so the response is almost 3 times of the size than what the actual normal processed HTML would be. This is just a small example of it

```
<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t
```

right now I have no idea how to approach this. To brake the response in chunks or ? If you have any suggestion have at it please.

**Update** ,  we figured out that is some kind of data size limit but we cant nail it

if we do

```
    wp_send_json_success(array( 
        'html' => substr($html, 0, 1830000),
    ));
```

data is passing trough

but with `1840000`

it is failing ,

our test server is **nginx** and in litespeed config `client_max_body_size` is set at 500M so we are not sure what this 1.8M limit is.

Comment: Do you have the access of the service call/api to make any change?

Comment: @SudipPal yes I can make any changes to JS or PHP ,

Comment: Before sending the JSON data over http request, do some clean up for junk characters. Example: use replace method to replace "\r" to ""(blank) and so on. Hope this helps to reduce the count.

Comment: I would recommend you process the html locally. I think you should receive a simple JSON and generate the html as soon as the response is received. User/Client and server will be thankful.

Comment: @w35l3y that is what I am thinking about to , I am kinda forced to this process since I am dealing with a framework https://github.com/ThemeFuse/Unyson/issues/1545  but will try to find replacement for php process via JS instead